# Does this method fail in proving the given inequality?

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, alternative-proof, hyperbolic-functions

I have this inequality
$$   \frac{\frac{(1-2 a)x^3}{2}\;\coth  \frac{(1-2 a)x^3}{2}   }{\frac{x^3}{2}\;\coth  \frac{x^3}{2}   } <1 , $$
and I want to show that it is valid for $0<a<1$ and $x>0.\;$ To do this, defining $f(y) = y\coth y$, the inequality reduces to

$$   \frac{f(\frac{(1-2 a)x^3}{2}) }{ f(\frac{x^3}{2})} <1 . $$

Now, it is sufficient to show that $f(y)$ is increasing. Calculating $f'(y)$, I obtain $f'(y) = \frac{\sinh 2 y \;-\;2 y}{2 \sinh^2 y}$, which is positive but only for $y>0$, but the argument $\frac{(1-2 a)x^3}{2}$ for $a> \frac{1}{2}$ is negative, which means that I can not use this method, or it needs some further assumptions. If so, I will be grateful if someone suggests other ways that work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $1-2a = b$,
so $-1 < b < 1$,
you want to show that
$\dfrac{f(bx)}{f(x)}
\lt 1$
where
$f(x)
=x\coth(x)
$.

Looking at
$f(x) = x\coth(x)$,
$f$ is even,
$f(x) \ge 1$ and
$f(x) > 1$ for $x \ne 0$,
$f'(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$
and
$f'(x) < 0$ for $x < 0$.

Therefore,
if $x \ne 0$ and
$|b| < 1$
then,
since $bx$ is closer to zero
than $x$,
$1 \lt f(bx) \lt f(x)
$
if $|b| < 1$.

Comment: Simple and elegant (as usual) !